# Difference between notifyDataSetChanged() and Adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am new to programming. Can you please explain what the difference between `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `Adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged()` is? I think it has something to do with that context stuff?
I´m wondering which one I should use for my RecyclerView changes.

Answer (score 0):

They are likely one and the same. `this` is a Java keyword to specify the current object, and the only reason you would have to specify `Adapter.this` before the method is if you were in an inner class where `this` would refer to something else.